# Is it possible to feature test for dataTransfer.files support?

Tags: drag-and-drop, modernizr, browser-detection, feature-detection

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) provides a way to detect if browser has support for drag and drop, but it fails to adequately tell if browser supports drag and drop for files. Is it possible to feature test this? Or it's kind of thing that still requires browser sniffing?

Answer (score 2):

use `Modernizr.filereader` to detect

dataTransfer is one of the [undetectables](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/Undetectables) as not all browsers expose it (like webkit) so detecting if FileReader should do the trick. And i cant remember which browser it was in (android/safari etc) but the file was exposed in `target.files` instead of `dataTransfer.files` so detection if the object actually exists while in the firing event is best.

```
if( typeof(e.dataTransfer) !== 'undefined' && typeof(e.dataTransfer.files) !== 'undefined' ) {
    files = e.dataTransfer.files;
} else if( typeof(e.target.files) !== 'undefined') {
    files = e.target.files;
} else {
    //Bail out
}
```